# Want to take Facebook Page posts and turn them into blog post

Tags: plugins, facebook

My client has a Facebook page where he posts all his news. We want to simplify the process of double posting by finding a way that takes Facebook Page posts and turns them into WordPress blog posts.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rachel, welcome to WPSE. Please note that Plugin suggestion is off topic here. You need to ask something that is [on topic in WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You may check [how to ask a good question in WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to meet the guidelines. If you develop a new plugin yourself for this, then show us your work and ask what is not working or how to improve.